# Twitter sign in/login button implementation on web app? How to integrate if Twitter does not provide user email?

Tags: twitter, authentication

I'm trying to implement a "sign in with twitter" button on my web application. Upon authentication I receive the users' credentials which do not include a user email address. Twitter does not provide user email addresses and so I've heard people use the twitter unique id to identify distinct users.

My application allows a traditional mode of registration (user creates an account with us) as well as sign in with facebook. In order to determine in my database whether the user already exists we use the email address provided under these two sign in methods, but twitter does not allow for that.

Sure, I could ask for their email address the first time they sign in with twitter but this poses a number of security concerns, for example, the user may provide another person's email address.

The question is, how can I, with the unique twitter id or other information provided by twitter, determine, short of asking for their email address, if the user already exists in my database?

I've seen people puzzled over the fact that twitter sign in credentials do not include email address?

I appreciate any ideas on how to solve this.

Thank you.